# Create a PR in BitBucket with a commit

Tags: bitbucket, commit

I am programmatically trying to create a PR in Bitbucket for a single commit. I am not supposed to create a new remote branch as some new requirements.
The flow is:

```
git checkout somebranch
git checkout -b <new_local_branch>
make changes
git add -A && commit -m "some cool change"
hash = <get commit hash>
```

bitbucket-url = https://servername/rest/api/1.0/projects/owner-key/repos/project-name/pull-requests.

OLD STUFF - pushing & creating PR

```
git -push .... -u set up-stream blah blah
String formData= "{\"title\": \"New PR for $somebranch\",\"fromRef\": {\"id\": \"new-local-branch\"}, \"toRef\": {\"id\": \"refs/heads/$somebranch\" }}"
curl -v ${pullRequestRestUrl} -u user:pass  -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data ${formdata}
```

NEW requirements:
Change formData to push changes for the last commit> to Bit Bucket.
I am trying to figure how to include last commit hash to create a new PR w/o pushing to a branch.
The idea here is to get the changes from .git/... into the form.
Thank you!